# The collection property 'identifierUris' cannot be used in a 'where' query expression

Tags: azure-active-directory

Using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.ActiveDirectoryClient api I am trying to find an existing Application in AAD which has the same as my desired IdentifierUrl. This is so i can decide on creating one or leaving the existing one alone.
I'm using the following calls. However I get this error:

```
The collection property 'identifierUris' cannot be used in a 'where' query expression. Collection properties are only supported as the source of 'any' or 'all' methods in a 'where' query option
```

What is the recommended way of doing this? thanks

```
    public static async Task<IApplication> FindApplicationByUrlAsync(string accessToken, string tenantId, string identifierUrl)
    {
        var graphClient = NewActiveDirectoryClient(accessToken, tenantId);
        var matches = await graphClient.Applications.Where(app => app.IdentifierUris.Contains(identifierUrl)).ExecuteAsync();
        return matches.CurrentPage.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Any function:

```
var result = await client.Applications.Where(a => a.IdentifierUris.Any(i => i == identifierUri)).ExecuteAsync();
```

That'll get translated into a request as follows:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications?$filter=identifierUris/any(c:c eq 'yourIdentifierUri')
```

More info on filters for the **Azure AD Graph** here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options